# Get all the video ID's from a YouTube playlist into a PHP array using YouTube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm adding a custom player to my website and I have two issues.

1. My playlist on YouTube has 391 songs and the API player only loads 200.
2. I have problems shuffling the list using the API commands.

Here's the code that I'm using to call to the player:

```
<div class="videoplayer" id="ytplayer"></div>
<script>
    var getRandom = function(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    };

  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '50',
      width: '400',
      events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady
       },
      playerVars:{        
        list:'PLH30k6CwlcgK8C-LET6_ZrAWwYGLqT8R-',
        index:parseInt(0),
        suggestedQuality:'small',
        controls:0,
        autoplay:1
        }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
     event.target.setShuffle();
     event.target.setLoop();     
   }
</script>
```

I tried to workaround the shuffle thing using:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
         var num = parseInt(getRandom(1,391));
         event.target.playVideoAt(num);   
       }
```

But it doesn't work like I want, so I want retrieve the ID's of all the videos in the playlist into an array, mix them and pass all the array to load each video. I was trying to use some examples from previous questions but those examples are not working anymore, if some of you guys has examples with the v3 of the YouTube API or actually working examples I will appreciate it.

Regards.

Comment: Please can you review the title of your question? It does not look to fit the question?

Comment: Yes it fits, because I want to get all the video ID's from a youtube playlist using the YouTube API via php

Comment: Where does the `target` come from? I'm probably looking straight past it.

Comment: This answer taught me how to get all video IDs from a YouTube playlist using javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723612/470749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to use iframe API
because, javascript API is outdated and deprecated

Look for [youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr) (list of deprecated api's on left side menu)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr

replacing

```
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
// by 
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

and

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()
// by 
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
```

## 0 To fix shuffling, try to randomize at each end state

by using onPlayerStateChange event listener, and YT.PlayerState.ENDED
state.

## 1 You need to CUE the playlist to get whole video's ids

before the randomization.
and get them with proper method : [getPlaylist()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr#getPlaylist)

```
var player;
var videoList, videoCount;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
{
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer',
    {
        height: '50',
        width: '400',
        events:
        {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        },

        playerVars:
        {
            controls:0,
            autoplay:0
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event)
{
    // cue the playlist, to get the video's ids 
    event.target.cuePlaylist
    ({
        listType: 'playlist',
        list: 'PLH30k6CwlcgK8C-LET6_ZrAWwYGLqT8R-',
        suggestedQuality:'small',
        autoplay: 1,
        index:0,
    });

    event.target.setLoop();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event)
{
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED)
    {
        videoList = event.target.getPlaylist();

        // to prevent adding new video and for the randomize
        videoCount = videoList.length; 

        // get the ids before randomize playlist, send it
        sendIds(videoList);

        // starting the player (like autoplay)
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // randomize at each video ending
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
    {
        var num = getRandom(1,videoCount);
        event.target.playVideoAt(num);
    }
}

function sendIds(ids)
{
    console.log(ids);
    // make what you want to do with them... ajax call to your php
}
```

Comment: It's working but there are some issues, the playlist still loading 200 songs, at the beginning it displays 391 songs, but then the amount change to 200 and the random index too.

Comment: And another concern than I have is if I add more videos in the future, the amount will be growing up and I don't want update the code every time, would be better always get the updated quantity of videos on the playlist and pass it to the getRandom function.

Comment: try to play with .getPlaylist() method (seem's to be cued before)

Comment: what does this function do? and where i should use it?

Comment: how do you want to use the list of video's ids ? you talking about php, can you explain more ?

Comment: I want to retrieve all the videos ID's of the playlist, put them into an array, "shuffle" the array content and instead passing the playlist ID YouTube says than I can pass a simple string or an array of video ID's and they will be played in that order, that's kind of solution for me.

Comment: okay you just trying to find the better way to having a self shuffled order of video ? i don't think this will solve your mismatches issue about 200 blocked list. And why do you talking about php ? what's php need to do here ??? just an occasion to grab the whole youtube ids list of videos to storing them ?

Comment: get them making an API request using CURL because my web site is on codeigniter

Comment: okay then , this javascript array you will provide you to make your self randomize and sending it via an ajax query to your php. i'm right ?

Comment: look for updated code, (my bad, i believed you talking about the "youtube" php api...)

Comment: Yeah, or I can do the request on my controller and pass it to the view that is displaying the YouTube player

Comment: new update where random size is auto managed. (to making what you are saying, controller may use php youtube to get the playlist length and ids directly!)

Comment: Your corrections were very helpful, I still struggling with the quantity of videos displayed but your answer is a very good kickoff :D thank you very much @MTroy