# Youtube iFrame Api playlist limited to 200

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

when I want to cue a huge playlist (about 500 playlist-items/videos) then it looks like the limit is 200. Items are above this limit simply "ignored" and I can't point to them with the "index". So when a video position is i.e. 244, then its invisible for the Api (red play button and black background).

```
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
  playerVars: {'autoplay': 0,}, events: {
    'onReady': function (event) {
      console.log("init: youtube playlist");
      event.target.cuePlaylist({list: playlistListId, index: playlistPosition, startSeconds: 0, suggestedQuality: "hd720"});
    }, 'onStateChange': OnPlayerStateChange
  },
});
```

So this is the code. The playlistListId is a big youtube playlist (533 videos) and shown only first 200.

How can I modify this script to show all the playlist-items/videos, or at least to show the positioned video?

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635614/get-all-the-video-ids-from-a-youtube-playlist-into-a-php-array-using-youtube-ap

Comment: @juvian I've tried now, but its not a solution for the limitation :|

Comment: Might try retrieving playlist and then playing individual videos

Comment: @juvian the problem is, I can't retrieve the full-length playlist :O   It getting become a much pain in my ass becouse all the playlists are huge, I mean contains more than 200 videos, and I'm unable to point to the right position if its out of range

Comment: I only know that the 200 limit got removed in v3 api, maybe that method doesn't work though

Comment: @juvian where did you read that? could you please send me a link?

Comment: this should work : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&playlistId=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC saw it on https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/issues/173

Comment: @juvian python not available for me

Comment: Its not the python that matters, but that it is possible with the api I linked

Comment: It's only 100 here...

Comment: @juvian it's not possible to add more than 200 videos with YouTube IFrame API